# can not name the title for navigation bar after adding segmentcontroller to titleView

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

My view right now is containing 3 `uitabbaritem`. At the first tab, I am adding a `segmentcontroller` to `self.navigationItem.titleView` by following

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    // Enable 'segmentControl' on navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView               =   self.segmentedControl;
}
```

What ends up is

[image]

Next, when I switch to the second uitabbaritem, I hide the segmentcontroller and name the title for the navigation like below

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    if ( item.tag == 1 ) {
        self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden    =   NO;
    }

    if ( item.tag == 2 ) {
        self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden    =   YES;
        self.title          =   @"support";
    }
}
```

However, after clicking on the second uitbarbatitem, the title is not displayed on the navigation bar..
[image]

Please advice me if you know what I have done wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` is not shown when there is a `titleView` set, no matter if it's hidden or not. You have to set the `titleView` to `nil`.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
  if ( item.tag == 1 ) {
      self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentedControl;
      self.title = nil;
  }

  if ( item.tag == 2 ) {
      self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
      self.title = @"support";
  }
}
```